# How to Manage Lots of Handlers in React

Tags: reactjs

I have several components in a hierarchical structure each of which need several event handlers, handed down through multiple layers. This is what I have in `App.js`:

```
...
<Files
  plugins={this.state.plugins}
  folders={this.state.folders}
  hover={this.state.hover}
  editing={this.state.editing}
  onClickFolder={this.handleClickFolder}
  onCreateFile={this.handleCreateFile}
  onCreateFolder={this.handleCreateFolder}
  onDeleteFolder={this.handleDeleteFolder}
  onMouseEnterFolder={this.handleMouseEnterFolder}
  onMouseLeaveFolder={this.handleMouseLeaveFolder}
  onStartRenameFolder={this.handleStartRenameFolder}
  onRenameFolder={this.handleRenameFolder}
  onClickFile={this.handleClickFile}
  onDeleteFile={this.handleDeleteFile}
  onMouseEnterFile={this.handleMouseEnterFile}
  onMouseLeaveFile={this.handleMouseLeaveFile}
  onStartRenameFile={this.handleStartRenameFile}
  onRenameFile={this.handleRenameFile}
  onStopEditing={this.handleStopEditing}
  onRightClick={this.handleRightClick}
/>
...
```

Then in `components/files.jsx`:

```
...
<FolderList
  src={[]}
  hover={props.hover}
  editing={props.editing}
  folders={props.folders}
  onClickFolder={props.onClickFolder}
  onCreateFile={props.onCreateFile}
  onCreateFolder={props.onCreateFolder}
  onDeleteFolder={props.onDeleteFolder}
  onMouseEnterFolder={props.onMouseEnterFolder}
  onMouseLeaveFolder={props.onMouseLeaveFolder}
  onStartRenameFolder={props.onStartRenameFolder}
  onRenameFolder={props.onRenameFolder}
  onClickFile={props.onClickFile}
  onDeleteFile={props.onDeleteFile}
  onMouseEnterFile={props.onMouseEnterFile}
  onMouseLeaveFile={props.onMouseLeaveFile}
  onStartRenameFile={props.onStartRenameFile}
  onRenameFile={props.onRenameFile}
  onStopEditing={props.onStopEditing}
  onRightClick={props.onRightClick}
/>
...
```

And so on with two more files. As you can see the code is starting to look quite messy and is against the concept of DRY (don't repeat yourself) in programming, since when I create a new handler I have to update all four files. What I'm asking is if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: I suggest you use React's Context API. this is gonna fix your DRY problem

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)**, **[context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)** or **combine your handlers** into one object and pass it to your child components, the fields of this object you can validate using [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) :)

Also, these [examples](https://medium.com/trabe/passing-callbacks-down-with-react-hooks-4723c4652aff) can helps you

Answer (score -1):

You have many options. Carefully go through this page. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component